# Avro schema for record type with empty object

Tags: avro, spark-avro, avro-tools

I am trying to create avro schema for below json

```html
  {
  "id": "TEST",
  "status": "status",
  "timestamp": "2019-01-01T00:00:22-03:00",
  "comment":  "add comments or replace it with adSummary data",
  "error": { 
    "code": "ER1212132",
    "msg": "error message"
  }
}
```

the error object is optional, it could be
"error" :{}
Below is the avro schema without default value

```html
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "Order",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "id",
    "type" : "string"
  }, {
    "name" : "status",
    "type" : "string"
  }, {
    "name" : "timestamp",
    "type" : "string"
  }, {
    "name" : "comment",
    "type" :  ["null","string"],
    "default": null
  }, {
    "name" : "error",
    "type" : {
      "type" : "record",
      "name" : "error",
      "fields" : [ {
        "name" : "code",
        "type" : "string"
      }, {
        "name" : "msg",
        "type" : "string"
      } ]
    }
  } ]
}
```

How can I add default value {} for error field in json.

Answer (score 0):

```html
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "Order",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "id",
    "type" : "string"
  }, {
    "name" : "status",
    "type" : "string"
  }, {
    "name" : "timestamp",
    "type" : "string"
  }, {
    "name" : "comment",
    "type" :  ["null","string"],
    "default": null
  }, {
    "name" : "error",
    "type" : [{"type": "record", "fields":[{"name": "code", "type":"string"}, {"name": "msg", "type":"string"}]}, {"type": "record", "fields":[]}]
  
  } ]
}
```